# Sublime Text syntax highlight Jinja2

Tags: python, html, sublimetext2, jinja2

Is there syntax highlight for Jinja2 templates in Sublime Text? By Jinja2 I mean:

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if task == 'archimed_spiral' %}
    {% include 'archimed.html %}
{% elif task == 'gcd' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I believe it is based on Python. And it can be pretty hard to read.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, [there is a Jinja2 package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Jinja2) for Sublime Text.

It is implemented as a TextMate syntax bundle; these are directly supported by Sublime Text, and was written by the author of the Jinja2 package himself.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it - does it highlight also the html syntax?

Comment: There are two modes: *Jinja Templates* and *HTML (Jinja Templates)*. The latter is a full HTML mode plus Jinja syntax.

Comment: Works nicely, although it might be better to use different colors for Jinja2 and html.. Now it kinda blurs together. But I guess it is better than before. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How do you set it in Sublime that it always opens .html as a HTML (Jinja Templates)

Comment: @Wavesailor: with a `.html` file open, use View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... -> Jinja2 -> HTML (Jinja2). See [How to customise file type to syntax associations in Sublime Text?](//stackoverflow.com/q/8088475)