# If statement on for statement in Jinja2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, if-statement, jinja2

I have a website hosted in GAE and within my Jinja2 template I have an IF statement in a FOR statement.

I have enabled my **jinja2.ext.loopcontrols** loop control using:

```
template_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
ENV = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                                       autoescape=True,
                                       extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape',
                                                   'jinja2.ext.loopcontrols'])
```

My template looks like this:

```
{% for i in data %}
  (% if i.date_posted is defined %)
    {{ i.date_posted.strftime('%d %b %Y') }}
  {% else %}
    No
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I keep getting the error:

> TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endif'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't declare your `if` tag properly:

```
(% if i.date_posted is defined %)
```

Note the parentheses instead of curly braces; it should be written like:

```
{% if i.date_posted is defined %}
```

Comment: Ah man! all that for something so simple. Maybe its time I get new glasses. :) Thanks!

Comment: @JasperJohns: What editor do you use? I use the [Jinja2 syntax bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870627/sublime-text-syntax-highlight-jinja2) for Textmate and Sublime Text, and it'd make the difference more obvious.

Comment: I am using Aptana Studio 3, is Sublime Text free?  I just had a look at it and I like it a lot so far. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @JasperJohns: Sublime Text is free to evaluate; it'll nag you from time to time when you save a file to buy a license for continued use. Sublime Text 3 is currently in beta and free until it is officially released.

Comment: @JasperJohns: Apparently Aptana Studio 3 supports Django templates; Jinja2 is heavily based on the same syntax, you could try and see if the Django template syntax highlighter helps.

Comment: Thanks but I'm gonna try Sublime Text for a bit, its nice and lightweight - Aptana takes ages to start-up. I might even pay for it once South Africa's exchange rate gets a bit stronger.

Comment: Couldn't agree more; you have to pry Sublime Text out of my cold, dead hands before I touch a Java behemoth like Aptana Studio.