# Using Jinja2 strings with spaces as HTML attributes

Tags: python, html, jinja2

If I pass Jinja2 a string that contains a space, such as:

```
myStr = "my string" #a google.appengine.ext.db.StringProperty
```

And then render it, e.g.:

```
<div class={{ myStr }}>
```

The generated HTML is:

```
<div class="my" string>
```

I have tried fixing this by creating filters to replace the space with `%20` or `&nbsp;`, but it seems neither is valid, the literal string is rendered, as in `<div class="my&nbsp;string">`.

The only method I have found that does actually render the expected result is:

```
<div class="{{ myStr }}">
```

But this is an undesirable style; not least because it completely breaks (the 'official') syntax highlighting.

Note that this affects all attributes (that I have tried), not just `class`. (It seems reasonable to want a space in `title` for example).

What am I missing, how is this supposed to be handled?

Comment: Your "undesirable" style is in fact absolutely the *correct* way to do it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Then [the 'official' highlighter](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2-tmbundle) has a bug? This is highlighted like HTML, which makes it seem as if "{{" will be in the output.

Answer (score 10):

Jinja 2 does no such thing to the rendered HTML; it is your *browser* that will trip over the lack of quotes around the attribute. In essence you are generating:

```html
<div class=my string>
```

and that means that the parts after the space are **new attributes**, not part of the `class` attribute. You'll notice that the code prettifier colours `my` and `string` differently; `string` is coloured just like `class` is.

Add in attributes to delineate the attribute properly:

```html
<div class="{{ myStr }}">
```

to produce the output

```html
<div class="my string">
```

If this breaks your highlighter, get a better syntax highlighter. For TextMate and Sublime Text the Jinja author has [provided a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870627/sublime-text-syntax-highlight-jinja2), and he also produced one for [ViM](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1856).

Yes, the Sublime Text highlighter does not highlight Jinja2 constructs in HTML attributes:

> [image: Sublime Text 3 highlighting of Jinja2 template code]

This is probably by design and not a sign you did something wrong.

Comment: @OllieFord: `"" + myStr` adds an empty string in front of the string. If your highlighter breaks, get a better highlighter, that should never be a reason to produce invalid HTML output.

Comment: Agh, I see. The highlighter is the one from Jinja's author for that you posted elsewhere :). Is a filter that does `return '"'+string+'"'` a reasonable solution?

Comment: @OllieFord: not if you have automatic escaping enabled; quotes will be replaced by `&quot;`.

Comment: @OllieFord: I have no such problems in Sublime Text 3 when using the Jinja renderer, by the way.

Comment: I'm using ST3 + jinja2-tmbundle on Mac, the attribute is highlighted in exactly the same way as SO does above - like HTML only. `{% for x in y %}` etc. are correctly rendered in "HTML (jinja templates)", however.

Comment: @OllieFord: are you certain you enabled it *for the current file*? `CMD-Shift-P`, then type `Jinja` and select the *Set Syntax: HTML (Jinja Templates)*, or use the *View -> Syntax -> Jinja2 -> HTML (Jinja Templates)* option.

Comment: @OllieFord: and yes, `{{ ... }}` inside attributes are rendered as attributes. *That is by design*. But if you are breaking HTML output just to get highlighting inside the curly braces, you cannot blame Jinja2 for the consequences.

Comment: Yes, I re-opened all with current ext. as such. Just tried the above again, no change. Like I said, `{%%}`s are correctly highlighted, but `"{{}}"` is not.

Comment: @OllieFord: right, as I said, any markup inside an attribute is not marked up separately. But you should only be interpolating in attributes anyway to keep the template clean and low on logic. That is probably a deliberate choice by Armin here. If you disagree, you can ask for a feature change there. However, *not using quotes around Jinja statements* is not a good way to go about this.

Comment: @OllieFord: Just stick with valid HTML output over forcing syntax highlighting to take place here.

Comment: Oh. I misunderstood - when you said you had no problems, I assumed you meant it marked up separately, which was what I was expecting to happen.

Comment: I'm not trying to hack syntax highlighting into place - it's the other way around - the lack of it made me think I was doing it wrong.