# How to use sublime 3 jinja2 highlighter

Tags: python, sublimetext3, jinja2, syntax-highlighting, sublime-text-plugin

I have a problem with jinja2 highlighter in sublime 3.All the files associated with .html
 extensions don't recognize jinja templates blocks..I searched the web but the only solution I found is to make a .jinja.html custom extension..anyone got any idea how to solve this?..This is the plugin I installed https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Jinja2

Comment: If it isn't a true html file, why is the extension `.html`? Do you know what extension that plugin is associated with? Do you really need the syntax highlighting to be automatic?

Comment: And, if you see the comments on this post.  "There are two modes: Jinja Templates and HTML (Jinja Templates). The latter is a full HTML mode plus Jinja syntax"  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870627/sublime-text-syntax-highlight-jinja2

Comment: if one want to edit css file with jinja, try swapping the sublime text syntax highlighting to "sass"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `.j2` to your file extension:

`mysupertemplate.html.j2`

Have a look at the [syntax file](https://github.com/kudago/jinja2-tmbundle/blob/master/Syntaxes/HTML%20(Jinja2).tmLanguage) (under `fileTypes`)

Comment: I found out that there are 2 ways.The first is as math told above to add a .j2 extension in the html file and the other to ctrl+swift+p in sublime and SET syntax to HTML(jinja2).Thank you verry much