# How to indent Django templates properly

Tags: django, django-templates, sublimetext3

I work in SublimeText 3. When writing Django templates I have a mixture of html and functions.

I like to indent my code so that `block`, `if` and other such statements are indented. For example:

**Manual formatting**

```
{% extends "accounts/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Password changed</h1>
  <p>Your password was changed.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

However, when I run any autoformatter [HTML-CSS-JS-Prettify](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify) it ignores these brackets and treats them as text:

**After formatting**

```
{% extends "accounts/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Password changed</h1>
<p>Your password was changed.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Although plugins like [Djaneiro](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Djaneiro) give great tag highlighting, I haven't been able to find a way to get SublimeText to treat these as tags.

Has anyone had any luck?

Comment: There doesn*t *seem* to be any formatter that supports Django at this point. However, you might find this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/wK2PzdGNOpQ%5B1-25%5D) interesting.

Comment: Actually, [black](https://github.com/psf/black) supposedly supports formatting Django templates. So it sounds like you might be able to use [Sublack](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/sublack), but I haven't been able to get it running myself. Maybe you have more luck!

Comment: @idleberg If you are referring to `https://github.com/django/deps/blob/master/accepted/0008-black.rst` unfortunately it only supports python code, not templates.

Comment: Don't know for sublime, but pycharm allows to reformat code by going to Code -> Reformat code and it seems to work reasonably well enough. Maybe you can take a look

Comment: The [**Pycharm**](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) IDE supports this feature for a long time ago. Fortunately this feature available in both **Professional** and **Community** editions. They already created documentation regarding this feature here, [Reformat and rearrange code--(Pycharm Help)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html)

Comment: Does this thread answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870627/sublime-text-syntax-highlight-jinja2

Comment: @n1rna Jinja2 is mostly [compatible with Django, but not identical](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/switching/#django)

Answer (score 2):

This is a late answer, but I would like to mention a Django template formatter that I've created myself: [DjHTML](https://github.com/rtts/djhtml/). You can install it using `pip install djhtml`.

Let's say `template.html` contains the following:

```
{% extends "accounts/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Password changed</h1>
<p>Your password was changed.</p>
<script>
$(function() {
console.log("Password changed!");
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Then running `djhtml template.html` will give the following output:

```
{% extends "accounts/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Password changed</h1>
    <p>Your password was changed.</p>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            console.log("Password changed!");
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

It's easiest to use DjHTML as a [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) hook, so that templates will be automatically indented when you run `git commit`. Instructions on how to configure pre-commit can be found in the [README](https://github.com/rtts/djhtml/blob/main/README.md).

Comment: Thanks.:)  And it works also with Jinja template in Flask . (It's obvious because Django and Flask uses Jinja template : I write this also for keyword search in S.O.).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one for sublime text as far as I can tell. I have no source I can quote on this, but I have basically searched nothing came up.

This discussion is by any means old, but active. I found [this really old ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14831) about formatting standards for Django and it has been updated 9 Months ago to basically say they are "in favour of standards" and the proposed formatting for templates would be:

```html
  <ul>
    {% for x in y %}
      <li>{{ x }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

They also [made a place happen](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#template-style) that holds information about formatting guidelines in Django.

[You might find this discussion interesting as well.](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/156xgo/how_do_you_indent_your_django_templates/) It's old too, but it highlights the confusion about formatting in Django and the DIY solutions people came up with to cope.